# Is there an easier way to animate 3D models in XNA?

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, xna

Currently, I'm struggling to understand and do 3D animation in XNA.

My model originally looks like:
[image]

I don't want it with the arms out to the side like this. Using XNA, I tried to put the arms at the side and it ended up like:

[image]

The code I'm using is Microsoft's XNA Animation Sample:

```
public class SkinningSampleGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    /* Other stuff here */

    private Matrix rotate(float X, float Y, float Z)
    {
        return Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(X)) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(Y)) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(Z));
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float time = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        //transform the model's left arm.

        int boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:LeftShoulder"].Index - 3;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(-2.593f, 1.84f, -14.782f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(2, -3, 5)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];

        boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:LeftShoulder"].Index - 2;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(0, -30, -56f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-25, 2, -1)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];

        boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:LeftShoulder"].Index - 1;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(0, -2, -5f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];


        //Transform model's right arm (the messed up arm)..

        boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:RightShoulder"].Index - 8;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(-2.593f, 1.84f, 14.782f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(5, 3, 5)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];

        boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:RightShoulder"].Index - 7;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(0, 7, 56f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-15, -2, 1)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];

        boneId = currentModel.Bones["swat:RightShoulder"].Index - 1;
        animationPlayer.boneTransforms[boneId] = rotate(0, 2, 5f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) * _originalBonesMatrix[boneId];

        animationPlayer.UpdateWorldTransforms(Matrix.Identity);
        animationPlayer.UpdateSkinTransforms();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;

        device.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix[] bones = animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms();

        // Compute camera matrices.
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateScale(0.005f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(0)) * 
                      Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 1, 1), Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);

        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.1f, 1000f);

        // Render the skinned mesh.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in currentModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones);

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.35f);
                effect.SpecularPower = 16;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

The bones in the model are:
[image]

and I want it to be smooth like this:

[image]

How can I do this using XNA? Is there an easier way to animate the body parts? I spent the last 3 hours just doing the left arm and using trial-error to figure out how much to tranform each part.. it looks ok but it's not "great".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation of complicated 3D geometry is exclusively done using visual animation tools. And even with the right tools it will take many hours of practice to get it right.

There's a variety of free or commercial 3D modelling and animation software packages. To get started I would recommend taking a look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).